# how to combine wordpress htaccess on my root domain + php on subfolder

Tags: php, htaccess, apache, nginx

[image: Screenshot of htaccess code]

I apologise for a seemingly duplicate question, but none of the dozens I've looked at actually had the same problem.

I have the following directory structure:

```
/.htaccess
/index.php
/subfolder/.htaccess
/subfolder/index.php
```

I'd like all requests for pages to be handled by `/index.php`, unless the request starts `/subfolder` in which case it should be handled by `/subfolder/index.php`.

e.g. `/abc` to be rewritten to `/subfolder/abc`

e.g. `/subfolder/def` to be rewritten to `/subfolder/def`

I've been going round in circles over this, so any help will be massively appreciated.

Comment: Rather than include a screenshot of your code, it would be preferable to include the actual code. You've also tagged your question `nginx` - how is this relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything particularly special to get this to work. The mod_rewrite directives in the `/subfolder/.htaccess` file will naturally override the directives in the parent `.htaccess` file (in the root).

However, the "problem" would seem to be the following line (in both files):

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

You are rewriting to `/index.php` (that's `index.php` in the document root) in *both* files. You need to remove the slash prefix on the *substition*:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

You can do this in both files.

You already appear to set the `RewriteBase` correctly. By specifying a non-relative path in the *substitution*, you are overriding the value set in the `RewriteBase` directive.